# Python youtube-dl Issue

Tags: python, python-re, youtube-dl

I am trying to write a simple python script to search, download and convert a youtube video file using youtube-dl.

I have come across the following [code](https://github.com/aman-roy/mp3_downloader/blob/master/program.py) which takes a song name, searches for the corresponding youtube video and converts the video into an mp3 file.

However, the search_results variable is coming back as an empty list ([]). I have attempted to alter multiple things in the code such as specifying the decoding type (utf-8, etc) but still no luck.

Your help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. If any additional information is needed, please free to ask.

```
import re
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os
import sys

# download directly with a song name or link
def single_download(song=None):

    encode = urllib.parse.urlencode

    if not(song):
        song = input('Enter the song name or youtube link: ')  # get the song name from user

    if "youtube.com/" not in song:
        # try to get the search result and exit upon error
        try:
            query_string = encode({"search_query" : song})
            html_content = urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)

            if version == 3:  # if using python 3.x
                search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
            else:  # if using python 2.x
                search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read())
        except:
            print('Network Error')
            return None
        
        # make command that will be later executed
        command = 'youtube-dl --embed-thumbnail --no-warnings --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" ' + search_results[0]
        
    else:      # For a link
        # make command that will be later executed
        command = 'youtube-dl --embed-thumbnail --no-warnings --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" ' + song[song.find("=")+1:]
        song=video_title(song)

    try:       # Try downloading song
        print('Downloading %s' % song)
        os.system(command)
    except:
        print('Error downloading %s' % song)
        return None
```

Comment: When asking a question, you should submit [example]. Note "minimal". If the problem is that `search_results` is empty, why is the question tagged as [tag:youtube-dl]?

Comment: also this functionality is something that youtube-dl/yt-dlp simply offers out of the box: `--extract-audio --audio-format mp3 'ytsearch1:song title'`